# What is a good camera for a beginner looking to learn it all from a technical standpoint?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation

I am a graduate student in image processing and computer vision, and I'd like to get into photography.  I want to purchase a camera that isn't a black box, where I can experiment and learn about how and why.  I also don't want to be buying another camera a year from now.

What is the suggestion for this case?

Comment: If you end up getting into photography, no matter what you get you will learn the fundamentals and limitations of the equipment you do end up getting. That holds true for cameras across the board. I experiment with my 22 year old polaroid camera for example.

Comment: There are many answers now. Could you please mark the accepted answer. This would make it simpler for people looking for answers here.

Answer (score 12):

If you have the budget for it, I highly recommend a digital SLR camera in the mid-tier "prosumer" range. Currently, that's the Pentax K-5, Nikon D7000, Canon 60D, and similar. The brand isn't really important from this point of view, although you may want to [compare lens lineups](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9355/how-much-do-lens-lineups-vary-across-platforms). Read this [earlier answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5883/are-there-disadvantages-to-a-prosumer-camera-for-a-beginner-aside-from-cost/5889#5889) on [Are there disadvantages to a prosumer camera for a beginner, aside from cost?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5883/) for details, but the basic point is that these models have controls *designed to be used easily*. They don't necessarily let you do much more than what you could do with a lower-end model, but what they *do* offer is dials and buttons that control every important option directly and individually. This is far superior than having the same things buried several clicks deep in a menu.

Of course, this assumes a non-trivial outlay of money. And you'll probably want to budget an equal amount for lenses (and a flash) within the first year or two. That may be more than you want to jump in with, but if you do end up being serious about photography, you will not regret it. And the higher initial investment may even [save money overall](http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/2010/05/letter-to-george.html) (note: link is fictionalized).

If you do feel more comfortable starting at lower price point, a high-end point and shoot like the Canon S95 (or whatever is current) will give you a lot of flexibility and be a good starting point. But you probably won't be completely satisfied with it very long. On the other hand, a Canon P&S camera will let you run [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK), an open source firmware hack which could open up a lot of possibilities in line with your field of image processing and computer vision — if you don't get enough of that in your day (and night, knowing grad students) job.

Comment: +1 if you get serious about it at all, entry level cameras *can* get tiring quick - from a UI perspective

Comment: Yikes!  I agree entirely with your logic, but the d7000/60d are really pricey for a starving grad student :)  Maybe I'll start a savings account.

Comment: @coffee - if you act now, you may still be able to get a D90 new, which has all of the requisite controls, etc., with only slightly less capability than the D7000 and at just over half the price. Sometimes coming into the game just at the point of a generational change can pay off. (The 60D's predecessor was discontinued too long ago for it to be "new stock" anywhere now, and I haven't seen hide nor hair of an older suitable Pentax in quite a while.)

Comment: In terms of last generation of more pro cameras, the price on the Pentax K-7 has dropped quite a bit.

Comment: @Stan Rogers not that this is the place to ask for shopping advice, but half off where?!

Comment: @coffee - not half off the old price of the D90 (although that *would* be nice), but I've seen it for under $700 (body only), for instance at http://www.henrys.com/ , which is just over half the price of the D7000 and K5 and *considerably* less than the 60D. And the K-7 might fill the bill as well, but I haven't seen one in captivity in a while.

Comment: Amen. I have the Canon 500D, and operating in the manual mode is pretty cumbersome, as there is only one dial, as opposed to the two dials on the prosumer range. So given that the person asking the question wants to learn the how and why of photography, I would recommend the step-up to the prosumer range as suggested. But if you're on a budget it can solve the job.

Answer (score 5):

I was in the exact same situation a year ago, and I decided (without much reason, really) to go with the Canon EOS 550D. Until now, this turned out to be a good choice:

1. It's affordable with a student's budget.
2. It is fairly mainstream (you will likely be able to lend equipment from other people)
3. It allows you to shoot RAW.
4. It allows you to manually set/disable a great deal of the options (e.g. you can turn of flash compensation).
5. It allows you to (automatically or manually) trigger the shutter release from a connected PC.

The last three points are rather important if you want to implement e.g. a SIGGRAPH paper and use your camera to generate the images.

Of course, none of the above are characteristically for the EOS 550D. I am merely given you a list of things you should watch out for when buying a camera.

Comment: Informative answer!  Out of curiousity, is this camera the same as the rebel t2i?  Googling this camera generally brings results for that instead..

Comment: @coffee — yes, same camera. For whatever reasons, Canon uses different names for the same models in North America, Europe, and Asia — in Japan, it's the Kiss X4.

Comment: also, being a canon, you can use CHDK, which is probably something you will find interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need a camera where you could set the following;

- The aperture
- The shutter speed
- The ISO speed

These are the basic of the [exposure triangle](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle). This has been true for many years now. All modern DSLR will have this.

Other things to consider are:

- **How easy and user friendly the camera is**
- The ISO "performance", how well the camera handles low light condition where high ISO numbers are needed. This should be without too much noise.
- How fast/accurate the auto-focus is.
- Go for a well known brand, like Nikon, Canon, Pentax, Sony etc.

If you get a camera with these capabilities you will be able to learn and experiment with. Then go from there.

Do not forget to buy an extra memory card. I still remember my vacation photos from Moscow being destroyed by a bad memory card. An extra battery is also good, but not crucial. Take this into consideration when calculating your budget.

Do not bother with megapixels for now, since you want to learn the technical bits of the programming. I would not bother with video recording capabilities, since this is not really necessary for photographing.

Answer (score 1):

you can add Pentax K-r to your selection. I have its predecessor K-x and I am very satisfied with it. The price should be much better for K-r compared to K-5, but it has still many useful functions and settings. As I know you can also use standard AA NiMH batteries as a spare ones (cheaper than to buy second accu pack). And Pentax has very good support for old film camera lenses - the old Pentax AF lenses should work without problems and much older without AF with some limitations.

This could expand your possibilities to do some "creative experiments" without paying high amounts of money.

PS: do not know, how about other countries, but important thing for me is that I can spend more than 20% off the price if I order filters and other small equipment via Ebay directly from HongKong - especially genuine Hoya filters etc.

Comment: I have a K-x and am very happy with it too.  You don't need a higher end camera to learn about exposure etc, and the UI of some entry level models like that is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about studying photography and going to pursue it half-to-full time, you'll rack up your 10,000 hours pretty quickly, and can easily outgrow an entry-level dSLR body that might be a better fit for a weekend hobbyist shooter starting out.

In this case, the best recommendation for a "value sweetspot" is typically going to be a mid-range "prosumer" camera (in Canon terms, an XXD model or 7D; in Nikon a D7x00 or D3x0 series), **one generation back, used/refurbished.**

You want the mid-tier/prosumer model main for the better hardware UI (more dedicated physical controls, reducing menu diving), expanded menus and functions, more robust bodies, and better fast-action features.  You want one generation back used/refurbished, to get a camera that's depreciated into a more affordable range, but is still feature-rich compared to current models and is unlikely to be so old that the usable lifespan of the shutter box assembly in the camera could come into question.

Going by these criteria, I'd say look for a used/[refurbished Canon 60D](http://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/cameras/refurbished-eos-digital-slr-cameras/eos-60d-body-refurbished), or a used or [refurbished Nikon D7000](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Digital-SLR-Cameras/D7000-Refurbished.html), since the current models (at the time of writing) are the 70D and D7100.  Going factory refurbished will often be slightly more expensive than the used market, but the camera will have been thoroughly inspected/repaired by Canon/Nikon, and given a new-model warranty, and will still cost less than a brand new entry-level body kit.