# Are there any pro wildlife photographers using the Pentax DA* 300mm?

Tags: pentax, professional, wildlife

Are there any pro wildlife photographers using the Pentax DA★ 300mm? I have spent a week searching for anyone who is using Pentax kit in wildlife photography and who is getting paid for their work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aditya Panda](http://junglediaries.blogspot.com/) has [touched on it](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/pentax-slr-lens-discussion/73332-when-will-we-get-real-pentax-wildlife-lens.html) ([twice](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/members/8165-aditya-panda/)), and finds DA★ 300 quite superb but simply too short for wildlife photography. Unfortunately, the small user base means it's hard to design quality supertele lenses with competitive price. Also, [judging current lens lineup](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/9365/4390) and omission of full-frame body, Pentax seems to avoid expensive market niches. So, very likely wildlife photography using Pentax gear will remain challenging in near future.

UPDATE: Pentax has [announced](http://www.pentaximaging.com/about/press/287/PENTAX_Announces_Two_New_K-Mount_Lenses_) and [presented on Photokina 2012](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yh_086XUK_o&feature=player_embedded) a [560mm f/5.6](http://www.pentaximaging.com/camera-lenses/HD_PENTAX_DA_560mm_F5.6ED_AW) lens. While not from DA★ series, it will have AW weather sealing. There's also a focusing motor built into lens, but currently the specifications don't claim it to be a silent (SDM) one.

Comment: Hi Imre, thanks for the info and links. I have understood however that Pentax photographers are having success with a couple of teleconverters and SDM including  the Pentax F1.7X and Tamron 1.4X TC.

Comment: @Peter you're right; I removed the misleading statement on TC-s.

Comment: Too short? Isn't it already an effective 450mm? I don't shoot wildlife but that seems pretty long.

Comment: @dpollitt A 450mm equivalent lens might take you to a comfortable viewing distance from a deer or bear. Most of wildlife is much smaller though, and doesn't want you near.