# nikkon, sony or cannon

Tags: lens, canon, dslr, sony

I very new to DSLR Photography. Now I'm in confusion that Sony alpha 58 or Cannon D600.
both of them are nearly same cost. but I found that that for Sony there are less lens and accessories. but cannon have more lens and accessories are available.

I need camera that satisfy for a long period ( few Years )

Is sony alpha58 is pro than D600 in terms of Quality ?
What are the pros and cons of Sony and Cannon.

Comment: Please note that, in general, product recommendations are off-topic here (this is why your question is getting downvotes). Instead, try and explain the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of camera review sites where you can find out so much about the camera and quality, these are usually a little bias towards Nikon/canon as these are the big players.

A quick Google came up with this...

http://snapsort.com/compare/Nikon-D600-vs-Sony-SLT-A58

Personally you need to make sure the camera has the features that you actually require, which I expect both of these do. The next thing I would tell you other than just buying based on image quality (These are both technically very good cameras and unless you are going for large prints will not notice a huge difference in image quality as they will massively depend on which lens you use) you need to go and handle the camera before making a choice. The button layout on the cameras is really important and some are just plain annoying with having to dive into menus all the time to access features you use on a regular basis.

Some cameras are heavy so lighter so you really need to handle the camera before coming to any decisions on what to buy.

Hope that helps/

Comment: Note that the OP means the Canon 600D, not the Nikon D600 which is obviously a very different camera.

Comment: Thank you vary much. But I want to know about availability of lens and their cost in sony nickon and cannon ?

Comment: @sagar Ah, in that case, you are looking for http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9355/how-much-do-lens-lineups-vary-across-dslr-platforms