# Is it assured that every type of lens will be made for a given interchangeable lens camera?

Tags: lens

If I buy a Canon DSLR, can I be rest assured, that in future, I can put on any kind of lens on this camera. For example, is there guaranteed to be at least one of wide angle,telephoto,fish eye lenses that will mount on this camera? Or is it possible that the lens manufacturer will say that he does not make a fish eye for this particular camera make and model?

Comment: Voting to close on the basis that speculation about lenses and lens mounts is the same as speculation about unreleased cameras, which is [explicitly off-topic](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130/should-we-allow-questions-about-unreleased-cameras).

Comment: @PhilipKendall I disagree, there's no need to speculate in order to answer the question: **no**, it is absolutely not guaranteed that there will be one of each lens type available in the future! It is indeed *possible* for manufacturers to stop making a certain type of lens.

Comment: I edited the title, but I'm unclear on whether the question is actually specifically about buying a Canon DSLR now and worrying that Canon might not currently make all types of lenses (in which case I expect that it's a duplicate of the question about lens lineups), or if it's about a theoretical future Canon which might have (for whatever reason) a different mount (or if, indeed, Canon is just an example).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much do lens lineups vary across DSLR platforms?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9355/how-much-do-lens-lineups-vary-across-dslr-platforms)

Comment: As a Nikonian, I wish there was a lens that matched the Canon 400mm f/5.6L lens (yes, there's an f/2.8 but thats a different price).  I also suspect that no one else (besides Nikon once upon a time, and [Costal Optics](http://www.jenoptik-inc.com/coastalopt-standard-lenses/uv-vis-105mm-slr-lens-mainmenu-40.html) now), a [105mm UV lens](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/special/105UVmm.htm).  Clearly, there are differences in lens lineup. The Hasselblad Xpan had only 3 lenses made for it - super wide, wide, and normal - no fisheye or telephoto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no guarantees that any particular manufacturer will continue to produce lenses in any particular mount. They may choose to change their entire system. They may go out of business and produce nothing.

Having said that, you are probably safer with the Canon EF mount than any other mount currently on the market. This is true for several reasons.

- Canon's EF mount is a modern, 100% electronic connection between camera and lens introduced in 1987. This allows many future innovations to be added while still allowing for backwards compatibility with existing cameras and lenses. Theoretically, multi-channeling could be used over the existing number of pins if the need arises to move more data channels than is currently the case. Nikon's F-mount is three decades older and still uses mechanical linkages to control aperture and sometimes to effect auto focus, as do Sony/Minolta and Pentax mounts.
- Canon's EF mount has a shorter *registration distance (flange distance)* than other DSLR mounts. This allows lenses in other mounts to be mounted to a Canon body via adapter without requiring any additional optical elements in the light path. The reverse is not true.
- The diameter of the flange opening is larger in the Canon EF mount than most other popular mounts such as Nikon, Sony, Pentax, etc. This allows the potential for lens designs not possible using mounts with a narrower opening. This advantage has yet to be exploited by Canon, but it theoretically could be used in the future.
- As one of the world's two largest camera and lens manufacturers, there are hundreds of millions of Canon EF lenses and cameras that use them in circulation. And that number does not include the countless third party lenses that have been made for the Canon EF mount. Even if Canon stopped making lenses tomorrow, there would still be many available on the used market for years to come. And with as many Canon bodies as there are in use around the world, even if Canon stopped making lenses tomorrow the opportunity to fill a market demand would almost certainly insure that third party manufacturers would continue to make lenses in the EF mount for years to come as long as the market demand for them was there.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with your line of reasoning in regards to longevity. When company stops supporting the mount everyone else stop doing it too, in the business sense there is just no point in working on dying market, you better invest into new tech. The best example of it would be M42, it was around for 30 years and was extremely popular, huge number of lenses were designed and produced, but after Pentax dropped support for it no one cared to take their place and you still can find amazing M42 glass sold for next to nothing.

Comment: Which is half the point of bullet point #4: If Canon stopped making EF lenses, the existing supply in circulation would mean there would be wide availability for quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

All Canon DSLRs currently support the EF lens system and any APS-c cameras support the EF-s lens system.  If there is a lens that you want with that mount, it will work on your camera (though some features of the lens may or may not be supported in some rare cases.)  There is no guarantee that Canon won't stop making EF lenses tomorrow and switch to a completely new lens system.  They've been on EF for quite a while and don't seem like they intend to change, but they can do whatever they want.  That wouldn't make all the EF and EF-s lenses currently in circulation vanish though, so if the lenses you want are available, then you don't have anything to worry about.

Comment: Even if Canon stopped selling lenses the day you buy your camera, there are so many EOS cameras in use that there would be third parties selling quality EF-mount lenses for years to come.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry.

The probability that Canon would change to a different mount that wouldn't take the current EF lenses is *extremely* remote. Even if they did that, pretty much every lens that you could want would be on Ebay. I have a Canon, and I'm not worried at all.

Comment: Two letters' worth of rebuttal (at least of the "extremely remote" bit): FD. Mounts change when they have to, although eBay, etc., have made finding used equipment less of a lifetime Holy Grail quest, that's for sure.

Comment: The question is _why_ Canon would change mounts? They dropped FD because it wasn't future-proof.

Comment: Probably the most obvious possibility is "mirrorless takes over the world and Canon produce only short registration distance lenses in the future". Substitute "Sony" for "Canon" and it's believable, but I fully admit Canon are in a very different situation.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's extremely remote, look at what Sony is doing to the A-mount, (and of course what Canon did to the FD mount). What's going to happen when EVFs and CDAF advance past OVFs and PDAF? What about when curved sensors become cheap enough to have on in every lens? There are many reasons to abandon a mount, when it makes commercial sense Canon will do it.

Comment: @MattGrum All you say is correct. But I think the fact that canon bit the bullet and modernized when they went to the all electronic EF mount in 1987 means they are less likely to have the technological need to abandon the EF mount before others that still have legacy mechanical connections incorporated in their systems.

Comment: FD *was* "future-proof" until the future came. Of all of the things one can try to predict, the future is the toughest.

Comment: And here we are in 2019. Canon's new short registration distance FF mirrorless mount allows EF lenses all the way back to 1987 to be used with a *spacing* adapter that does not reduce the functionality of those EF lenses in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Canon totally changed their lens mount once when they introduced the EF and EOS system. 
They may do something alike again.

Canon did change the system about 15 years ago in a way that compatible Sigma lenses have not been compatible any more to any of the newly (from that date) release bodies. 
That may happen again. 
(This particular issue may come down to existing incompatibility issues caused by Sigma not licensing the EF system - or so.)

At about the same time canon introduced the EF-S system that is designed to work on EOS bodies with APS film and on digital bodies with roughly APS size sensors. 
EF-S lenses ain't compatible with eos bodies that use EF only. That does include some of the better digital models which use "full frame" sensors or "crop 1.3" sensor formats. 
Canon may do something alike in the future. Who knows?

Well, EF lenses still work nicely on EOS bodies with EF-S mount.

However, within the EF/EOS system or EF-S/EOS System Canon did a far better job in keeping lenses and bodies compatible than they do on Flashlight or than Nikon did on lenses. (Some Nikonians may disagree here. But they may agree to that: For the inexperienced beginner it is more difficult to distinguish which lens is actually compatible (fully compatibly or partly) to which body just by looking at the name of the product or even its specs than it is with Canon products).

Short: 
If the body is made for EF-S, then EF and EF-S lenses will fit. 
If the body is made for EF, then only EF lenses will fit. 
(APS bodies and early digital bodies like 10D are exceptions here.) 
If the body is made for FD, then only FD lenses will fit.

You cannot (really and usably) adapt FD ot EF or EF-S. 
(If you ever think of adapting old glass then go for M42 or T2 mounts or alike.)
You bay be able to mend some EF-S lenses to make them work on a 10D.