# Canon EOS 750D or Nikon D5300, which one?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, used-equipment

I've got a Pentax K30 and I'm looking to upgrade my equipment, the reason being is that I'm finding it hard to find accessories for the Pentax and I have been looking further afield.

I've been looking at the Canon EOS 750D and the Nikon D5300. I'm a bit confused about which is the better one.

Castle cameras have offered me a 18-250 lens for £389.00 (with £200 part exchange for my Pentax).

London Camera Exchange have only offered me £150 part exchange for my Pentax with only the 18-55 lens attached.

The only difference is that on the cashback issue, London camera exchange are willing to help me fill out the complicated cashback form, as staff at Castle cameras can be a bit abrupt and won't help me with the form.

(Which do you think is the better deal?)

I do landscapes and documenting (*as in old buildings and streets before redevelopment*) and I don't know which one to choose. Can you help me decide please?

Both come with 18-55 mm lenses.

Comment: "*I'm finding it hard to find accessorie's for the Pentax*" what accessories are you looking for? I don't quite understand your reasoning, which starts with lack of accessories and ends with support for a cashback form. This seems to be a little all over the place.

Comment: Note that outside of lenses, most accessories are compatible across brands. Batteries are also camera-specific but since your camera can even use AA batteries, that is a mute point since those are vastly more common and any proprietary ones.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually very little difference between these cameras outside of their brand but that has an implication on what lenses you can have now and in the future, so you should read [How much do lenses vary across platforms?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/9363/1620) to understand what you would be getting into, since as you probably noticed, changing systems is costly.

From the specification side, the Nikon D5300 will be able to out-resolve the Canon since its sensor does not have an anti-alias filter. Image quality is reputed to be better on that Nikon which has much better low-light performance and greater dynamic-range. If your photography includes action, the Nikon's 39-point AF system (vs 19-point on the Canon) may prove better at tracking sujects.

Then there will be the issue of ergonomics. Moving from Pentax to any other brand will need a learning period. Which one you end up preferring is a personal choice but Canon's interface is more different to that of Pentax compared to the Nikon. In either case though, both these cameras are significant down sides compared to your K-30:

- They both have cropped viewfinders, unlike the Pentax which shows 100% coverage, so it will be difficult to frame precisely. This is probably the biggest setback in terms of usability.
- They have only one control-dial and fewer buttons, so expect to be less efficient and delve into the menu system more often.
- Neither are weatherproof or freezeproof, so you would not be able to shoot in rain, snow or very cold environments.
- Neither have built-in stabilization, so you will need to consider and potentially pay for stabilized lenses.
- You will lose the ability to use AA batteries to save you from an empty battery when it happens.

Comment: I'm using some old film bodies with a grip, just to be able to use regular batteries. This is something you will miss on either of the two cameras unless you opt for a grip, too.